# Having trouble installing mod_WSGI - can't find input file

Tags: mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up mod_wsgi for use with Django. I have apache2, apache2-dev, python2.6, python2.6-dev all installed, but I'm getting this error when running configure:

```
checking for apxs2... /usr/bin/apxs2
checking Apache version... 2.2.14
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 16):

I had the exact same problem. Installing the apache2-dev package solved it.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

I don't think the asker needs this answer anymore, so I answered for future readers with similar problems

Comment: Is there a way to do this on OS X, where apt-get isn't included?

Comment: @Inspire48, I'm on an ubuntu box. I solved this problem by reinstalling apache, but I'm not sure what part of installing the package really solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Install apache2-threaded-dev:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

I started writing that you may need to ensure that you have axps installed (you can do this by installing the apache2-dev package). but I notice that configure already found axps. I had a similar problem but configure was bailing on not finding this dependency. Maybe some similar dependency or write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the mod_WSGI 'configure' script in the mod_WSGI source code directory aren't you? Ie., in the same directory as the Makefile.in file that comes with the source tar ball.

Comment: Yep, there's no Makefile.in in there though, only have posix-ap1X.mk.in, and posix-ap2X.mk.in

Comment: Sorry, Makefile.in is created by the 'configure' script to be symlink to one of those other .mk files. The only reason it could fail to create it is if the directory isn't writable. Suggest you start with fresh directory of source code and ensure user you are running build as has write access to directory.

Answer (score 0):

mod_wsgi's configure script uses apxs to find the path to httpd:

```
apxs -q SBINDIR

apxs -q TARGET
```

Combine those with a "/" and add "-v", e.g.,

```
/blah/bin/httpd -v
```

That should run without an error. If it does not then mod_wsgi's configure script can't figure out the httpd version and you will get a broken symbolic link for Makefile.in.

For me, libpcre.so.0 wasn't in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Doing this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

then reconfiguring mod_wsgi and building fixed the problem.